# error System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola tengo este proble con mi programa, revise bien la capa de datos de permisos pero aun asi no me sirve, ayuda.
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Beyond.Herramientas.oPermisos.get returned null.

System.NullReferenceException

HResult=0x80004003

Message=Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Source=Beyond

StackTrace:

at Beyond.Herramientas.Herramientas_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
in C:\Users\ezpawn\source\repos\Beyond\Beyond\Herramientas.cs:line 63
[![using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using CapaModelo;
using CapaDatos;

namespace Beyond
{
public partial class Herramientas : Form
{
public string  nombre { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string FechaHora { get; set; }
public string password { get; set; }
public CapaModelo.Permisos oPermisos { get; set; }

```
    public Herramientas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   
private void Frm_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
    

    private void btnsalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea Salir?", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void iconButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var Iform = new IUsuarios())
        {

            Iform.BackColor = Color.Teal;
            var result = Iform.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Form FormularioVista = Iform.FormularioVista;
                this.Hide();
                FormularioVista.Show();
                FormularioVista.FormClosing += Frm_Closing;
            }
        }
    }


    private void Herramientas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblstatus1.Text = string.Format("{0}", email);
        lblstatus2.Text = string.Format("{0}", FechaHora);
        if (oPermisos.configuacion == 0)
        {
            btnsalir.Enabled = false;
            btnsalir.Cursor = Cursors.No;
        }

        if (oPermisos.registro_equipo == 0) 
        {
            btnregistroe.Enabled = false;
            btnregistroe.Cursor = Cursors.No;
        }
        if (oPermisos.mantenimiento == 0)
        {
            btnrmantenimiento.Enabled = false;
            btnrmantenimiento.Cursor = Cursors.No;
        }
        if (oPermisos.estadistica == 0)
        {
            btnestadistica.Enabled = false;
            btnestadistica.Cursor = Cursors.No;
        }
        if (oPermisos.inventario == 0)
        {
            btninvntario.Enabled = false;
            btninvntario.Cursor = Cursors.No;
        }
        if (oPermisos.calendario == 0)
        {
            btncalendario.Enabled = false;
            btncalendario.Cursor = Cursors.No;
        }
        

    }

    private void iconButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnrmantenimiento_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

    }

    private void btncalendario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void btnestadistica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var Iform = new IUsuarios())
        {

            Iform.BackColor = Color.Teal;
            var result = Iform.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Form FormularioVista = Iform.FormularioVista;
                this.Hide();
                FormularioVista.Show();
                FormularioVista.FormClosing += Frm_Closing;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btninvntario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
    }

    private void statusStrip2_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liOyx.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liOyx.jpg)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! imposible saber que pasa si no mostras el codigo, que para colmo, te dice la linea exacta donde esta el problema... igual, para esto, tenemos una solucion general...

Comment: no será que oPermisos.configuacion no existe, no quisiste poner oPermisos.Configuracion   ?? y bueno, realmente para preguntar necesitas poner aquí el código, no en foto, este no es un foro.

Comment: @Osaskoh Ya edite la pregunta, me dicen que lo debo instanciar, sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo edite amigo, me dicen que hay que instanciarlo, sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: en la pregunta relacionada, esta toda esa informacion que pedis. Igual.. en otros lugares instanciaste cosas.. no se que clase no esta instanciada.. pero deberias hacer el new correspondiente...